# Syntax error in Left Join in vb.net on access data base

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010

The following code in vb.net 2010 express generates this error:

> syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''.

```
sql = "SELECT Machines.LocationID FROM Lanes LEFT JOIN Cabinets ON
Lanes.CabinetID=Cabinets.ID AND Cabinets.Name IS NOT NULL LEFT JOIN Machines ON
Cabinets.MachineID=Machines.ID "

Dim mAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
Dim mt As New DataTable("Results")
mAdapter.Fill(mt)
```

`con` is defined in a module of the project as:

```
Public myConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
Public databaseName As String = "C:\vending.mdb"
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(myConString & ";Data Source =" & databaseName)
```

If I comment out the second Left Join command, the statement executes properly.  This exact same sql statement when executed from SQL Server works fine.

Tables are defined as:

**Locations**

```
ID INTEGER IDENTITY
Company
Name
...
```

**Machines**

```
ID INTEGER IDENTITY
LocationID Integer
Name as Text(100)
SerialNum as Text(100)
...
```

**Cabinets**

```
ID INTEGER IDENTITY
Name TEXT(100)
MachineID INTEGER
...
```

**Lanes**

```
ID INTEGER IDENTITY
Name TEXT(100)
CabinetID INTEGER
...
```

If I add parentheses around the join statements like so:

```
sql = "SELECT Machines.LocationID FROM ((Lanes LEFT JOIN Cabinets ON
Lanes.CabinetID=Cabinets.ID AND Cabinets.Name IS NOT NULL) LEFT JOIN Machines ON 
Cabinets.MachineID=Machines.ID) "
```

I get the error:

> Join expression not supported.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Good question. I've got the same kinds of problems and I could really use some comprehensive list of differences between T-SQL and Access SQL; does anyone know of something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Access requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause for any query which includes more that one `JOIN`.

Separate from that issue, I think you'll also need another pair of parentheses around that compound `ON` clause (the first of the two `ON` clauses).

This untested Access SQL looks correct to me, but I think you should build your own using Access' query designer if possible.  The designer knows about the join syntax which keeps the db engine happy, and will automatically add the required parentheses for you.

```sql
SELECT Machines.LocationID
FROM
    (Lanes
    LEFT JOIN Cabinets
    ON (Lanes.CabinetID=Cabinets.ID AND Cabinets.Name IS NOT NULL))
    LEFT JOIN Machines
    ON Cabinets.MachineID=Machines.ID
```

`Name` is a reserved word, and prefixing it with the table name or alias is one technique to prevent the reserved word from confusing the db engine.  Enclosing the field name in square brackets is another.  You can even combine both if you wish ... `table_name.[reserved_word]` ... for a "belts and suspenders" approach.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use the access designer to spit out the correct syntax.

Comment: SELECT Machines.LocationID                 "FROM " & _
                "((Lanes LEFT JOIN Cabinets ON Lanes.CabinetID=Cabinets.ID) " & _
                "LEFT JOIN Machines ON Cabinets.MachineID=Machines.ID) "